# wxPython GUI as a web-client

Tags: wxpython, client, web

I am currently working on a GUI for a science experiment. I am using wxPython.

I have done the design part and also the data logging in an SQLite database. Is it possible for the GUI to behave as a web-client and write data onto a website. I have a Kodingen account. Can this GUI write to my homepage everytime I run it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use httplib or similar to communicate with your website and use wxPython as the front-end. When you hit you're Submit button or whatever, you would call httplib or a similar library to post the data to your website. You might need to use threads to keep the GUI responsive.